# An Exercise in Beauville's book about Kodaira dimension

Tags: algebraic-geometry

VII.7
Let X be a smooth projective variety. Consider the algebra $\oplus_{n\geq 0}H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X(nK))$, and write d for its Krull dimension (i.e. the transcendence degree over $\mathbb{C}$ of its field of fractions). Show that:
its Kodaira dimension $\kappa(X)=d-1$, when $\kappa(X)\geq 0$.

I can do the curve case for $\kappa(X)=0$.

But consider a curve C, and genus $g(C)>2$, the $\kappa(C)=1$. $h^0(C,\mathcal{O}_C(K))=g>2$. However the $\mathbb{C}$-algebra generated by $H^0(C,\mathcal{O}_C(K))$ would have transcendence degree higher than 2.
This seems a contradiction to me. I think I must have a misunderstanding.

And also what about the general case for a variety of Kodaira dimension n?

Comment: Why does the algebra have to be generated in degree $1$?

Comment: Not have to. But if degree one already has a dimension higher than 2, then they must be algebraic depend, otherwise the transcendental degree will be >2, and Kodaira dim >1.  But I am not clear, how the elements in degree are algebraic dependent.

Comment: The transcendence degree is of course not the same as the vector space dimension. In fact since $H^{0}(\mathcal{O}(K))$ is a finite vector space, it cannot contain a transcendental element.

Comment: While I mean, it provides some transcendental generators of the grades algebra. For example the polynomial ring $k[x,y]$ is generated by $x, y$ as k-algebras.